# Any ways to find past week blocking session

Tags: sql-server

Any query to find past week blocking session in SQL server or blocking session which happen 2 weeks ago? Thanks

Comment: I think it's not possible with a Query, until unless you have trace file, monitoring tool for capture past data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are collecting the data in some way (monitoring tool, etc), you aren't going to be able to find the blocking session from a week ago or any time in the past.

Start collecting current activity to a table using sp_WhoIsActive. You can use [this method](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/07/logging-activity-using-sp_whoisactive-take-2/) to do it (I wrote the post).